# Exception in Input when clearing filled numeric textboxs

Tags: c#

When value is not set, clicking the clear form button does not cause an exception, but when a numeric value is inserted before clearing, an exception comes back. Other text boxes with string variables works fine.

```
  private void txtIngred4Sugar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float ing4S = (float)Convert.ToDouble(txtIngred4Sugar.Text);
    }

    void ClearAllText(Control con)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)c).Clear();
            else
                ClearAllText(c);
        }
    }

    private void clearForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearAllText(this);

    }
```

Exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Whats the exception message ?

Comment: So clearing the box makes it 0. And 0 isn't proper input I'm guessing. I'm ultimatly trying to be able to accept a whole number like '20' and also be able to have some decimal value like '20.5' as good user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details, I would say that your problem is this line

`float ing4S = (float)Convert.ToDouble(txtIngred4Sugar.Text);`

When you are clearing the textboxes, the `txtIngred4Sugar_TextChanged` event handler comes into play, but you are not checking to see if `txtIngred4Sugar.Text` is a number before trying to convert it.

`Convert.ToDouble` will throw an exception if the argument is not a number.

You should either put a Try..Catch around the statement, and handle the exception, or a neater way would be to use  the `Double.TryParse` method. See this MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more info on TryParse.